# Spring Boot: Configure 2 different varieties of the same class

Tags: spring-boot

Given the following classes, I'd like to configure 2 instances of the Composite class, one with FooA and one with FooB.

```
interface IFoo { }
class FooA implements IFoo { }

class FooB  implements IFoo {}

class Composite {

    private IFoo foo;
    public void setFoo(IFoo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }  
}
```

In a bean configuration file, I'd do this:

```
<bean id="fooA", class="FooA"/>
<bean id="fooB", class="FooB"/>
<bean id="compositeA" class="Composite">
    <property name="foo" value-ref="fooA"/>
</bean>

<bean id="compositeB" class="Composite">
    <property name="foo" value-ref="fooB"/>
</bean>
```

How can I accomplish this in a similarly terse manner in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty much exactly the same way I'd imagine, with a `@Configuration` annotated class in place of your beans xml file

```
 @Configuration
 public class SpringConfig {

     @Bean
     @Qualifier("compositeA")
     public Composite compositeA() {
         Composite c = new Composite();
         c.setFoo(fooA());
         return c;             
     }

     @Bean
     @Qualifier("compositeB")
     public Composite compositeB() {
         Composite c = new Composite();
         c.setFoo(fooB());
         return c;
     }

     @Bean
     public FooA fooA() {
         return new FooA();   
     }

     @Bean
     public FooB fooB() {
         return new FooB();   
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Qualifier is what I was missing!   With that, I see a more concise approach:

Answer (score 0):

With the Qualifier annotation pointed out by stringy05,  I've done the following.  FooA and FooB don't need to be specified as Beans in the @Configuration file.

```
// FooA.java
@Component
public class FooA implements IFoo {}

// FooB.java
@Component
public class FooB implements IFoo {}


// Inside a class annotated as @Configuration
@Bean
public Composite compA(@Qualifier("fooA")IFoo foo) {
    Composite c= new Composite();
    c.setFoo(foo);
    return c;
}

@Bean
public Composite compB(@Qualifier("fooB")IFoo foo) {
    Composite c= new Composite();
    c.setFoo(foo);
    return c;
}
```

For additional brevity (which I should have done in the first place), I'll give Composite a constructor that takes IFoo as an argument, thus reducing both Bean method bodies to

```
return new Composite(foo);
```